# SQL Server partitioned tables - nonclustered primary key - do I have to rebuild every time I want to swap partitions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, partitioning

I have a very large sales detail table in our DataWarehouse.

It has 5-7 nonclustered indexes, all partition aligned on date.
The clustered index is just on the date column.

I also have one nonclustered primary key set on an identity column.

If I want to do any form of partition swapping, I have to drop the primary key, then rebuild it when I am done.

Is there some other way to enforce the primary key while allowing me to swap partitions quickly? I want to swap out a partition to do processing on it, and this rebuild is unfortunately making that more time consuming then necessary.

I was considering adding saledate to the primary key, and then potentially making a unique constraint on the primary key column...but if I'm understanding correctly, a unique constraint just creates another nonclustered index that wouldn't be partition aligned.

Is there a solution to this, or do I have to suck it up and wait it out?

Comment: I don't get what you say. to switch partition, you need another table exactly like the source table, otherwise you cannot switch partition. so to do the job, you need to create a new table, make it partitioned using partition index (I think the date column), create all indexes, then switch partition.

Comment: Yes, but if you have non aligned indexes, you can't switch partitions, so you have to drop and rebuild them. From MSDN: To enable partition switching, all indexes on the table must be aligned.

Comment: Oops, I did not pay attention to word "aligned" :)